# When I use tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization() it throws a Type Error

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Using tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization() gives 
TypeError: Incompatible types:  vs. int64. Value is 0

use this link for error reproduction::
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16IEd1GjgvPIiG0xnB3ado11u4jLHQZLY

I want to make it trainable.

```
  enc = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu',padding = 'same',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))(enc)
  print('encoder_mask', enc.shape)

  enc = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(epsilon=BN_EPSILON, momentum=BN_MIMENTUM))(enc)
  print('encoder_mask', enc.shape)

  enc = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, activation='relu',kernel_size=3,kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))(enc)
  print('encoder_mask', enc.shape)
```

After I compile it the error I get is given below even if I dont use these variables (BN_EPSILON,BN_MIMENTUM ).

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-c9408a385d78> in <module>()
      1 lr = 0.0001
----> 2 train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr).minimize(reconstuction_loss)

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py in minimize(self, loss, global_step, var_list, gate_gradients, aggregation_method, colocate_gradients_with_ops, name, grad_loss)
    401         aggregation_method=aggregation_method,
    402         colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops,
--> 403         grad_loss=grad_loss)
    404 
    405     vars_with_grad = [v for g, v in grads_and_vars if g is not None]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py in compute_gradients(self, loss, var_list, gate_gradients, aggregation_method, colocate_gradients_with_ops, grad_loss)
    510         gate_gradients=(gate_gradients == Optimizer.GATE_OP),
    511         aggregation_method=aggregation_method,
--> 512         colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops)
    513     if gate_gradients == Optimizer.GATE_GRAPH:
    514       grads = control_flow_ops.tuple(grads)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py in gradients(ys, xs, grad_ys, name, colocate_gradients_with_ops, gate_gradients, aggregation_method, stop_gradients, unconnected_gradients)
    156         ys, xs, grad_ys, name, colocate_gradients_with_ops,
    157         gate_gradients, aggregation_method, stop_gradients,
--> 158         unconnected_gradients)
    159   # pylint: enable=protected-access
    160 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_util.py in _GradientsHelper(ys, xs, grad_ys, name, colocate_gradients_with_ops, gate_gradients, aggregation_method, stop_gradients, unconnected_gradients, src_graph)
    718               # issue here because of zeros.
    719               if loop_state:
--> 720                 out_grads[i] = loop_state.ZerosLike(op, i)
    721               else:
    722                 out_grads[i] = control_flow_ops.ZerosLikeOutsideLoop(op, i)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py in ZerosLike(self, op, index)
   1229       # If the shape is known statically, just create a zero tensor with
   1230       # the right shape in the grad loop context.
-> 1231       result = constant_op.constant(0, shape=shape.dims, dtype=val.dtype)
   1232       if dead_branch:
   1233         # op is a cond switch. Guard the zero tensor with a switch.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name)
    244   """
    245   return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
--> 246                         allow_broadcast=True)
    247 
    248 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    282       tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(
    283           value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape,
--> 284           allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))
    285   dtype_value = attr_value_pb2.AttrValue(type=tensor_value.tensor.dtype)
    286   const_tensor = g.create_op(

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    499                             dtype.base_dtype != numpy_dtype.base_dtype):
    500     raise TypeError("Incompatible types: %s vs. %s. Value is %s" %
--> 501                     (dtype, nparray.dtype, values))
    502 
    503   # If shape is not given, get the shape from the numpy array.

TypeError: Incompatible types: <dtype: 'resource'> vs. int64. Value is 0
```

Reproduce error by running this::

```
batch_size = 20
inp = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, 19, 64, 64, 3])
out = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, 19, 60, 60, 16])
def model(inp):

  enc = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, activation='relu', kernel_size=3,kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))(inp)
  enc = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())(enc)
  enc = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, activation='relu',kernel_size=3,kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))(enc)
  return enc

pred = model(inp)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.keras.backend.binary_crossentropy(out, pred))
lr = 0.0001
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr).minimize(loss)
```

Comment: Please add the full error message to your question

Comment: The code you provided works in tensorflow 2.0: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1kaq7E0DeMSCi9o0sl9AfEye8SQaoG5kf - please add more code, especially the compilation of the model

Comment: What are the types and values of `BN_EPSILON` and `BN_MIMENTUM`? (As printed)

Comment: @DanielMöller
BN_MIMENTUM = 0.1
BN_EPSILON  = 0.00002

even if I don't use these values then also I have to setup trainable = False

Comment: @Taxel issue arises when I compile it 
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr).minimize(reconstuction_loss)
my reconstruction loss is a combination of three binary crossentropy losses

Comment: Please provide a full example of code that produces the error, then where you set trainable to false in order to make it work and the full error message.

Comment: @Taxel done, it's just when I compile it and when I do 

tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(trainable=False))(enc)
it works

Comment: That's the full error message. Now please provide code that actually produces the error in full. I still have no idea how you define your model, there is no code  where you compile etc.

Comment: Even better would be a Google Colab link where the error is reproducible

Comment: @Taxel I have added the code just run it colab, and see if you can reproduce the error or not.

Comment: @Taxel did you try it?

Comment: You didn't send me a link to your colab. Also, you can try if you can reproduce it first by executing the cells. If you can't, the error is not part of the colab code and you need to add more

Comment: @Taxel here is the link https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16IEd1GjgvPIiG0xnB3ado11u4jLHQZLY

Comment: Now that is something we can work with. You can also add that link to your question in case someone else can fix this faster than me :)

Comment: Not sure where the problem lies (yet?), but I can't reproduce that it's working when I set `trainable=False` in the `BatchNormalization` - the exact same error is showing up

Comment: @Taxel oh yes I just removed that line from there, I realized that I tried trainable = False, but it didn't work, Sorry for that, If you remove that line from there it will work. Sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at a fixed version of your example:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19DQlzeD2oN8KU37SUFexRzEwrhQdyAe5

You weren't using the keras functional API correctly - this is the conventional way to do it. You can find more information [in this tf.keras guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/keras/functional)

Comment: There is no change in it can you see that again?

Comment: Oops, the colab was in playground mode. Updated the link.

Comment: This basically have turned into a keras model, I can't train it by passing values to tensor as there is no tf computational graph, this is just a small part of my whole code. I don't know why the BatchNormalisation layer when inserted throws an error. This is a conventional way how you do that in keras, I just want to use keras layers at the place of tensorflow layers that's it.

Comment: but I tried removing the time distributed layer from the batch normalisation and it worked